# Shell coding system

Tags: shell, character-encoding, process, comint

If,  before `M-x shell`, I run `C-x RET c`
(`universal-coding-system-argument`) I can change the coding system used by the shell.
Therefore, given

```
echo Straße > foo
```

`foo` will be encoded in the related CS.

How can I change the coding system after issuing `M-x shell`?

More generally, how can I set comint input/output encoding?

Answer (score 1):

As regards Linux, the behaviour can be controlled by with:

```
(setenv "LANG" ENCODING)
```

before calling `M-x shell` and after from the shell buffer with:

```
(set-buffer-process-coding-system INPUT-ENCODING OUTPUT-ENCODING)
```

Both should be set to a value compatible with the string to be represented. UTF-8 encoding family should work in most of the cases.

To learn about current encoding, we can use:

```
(getenv "LANG")
(process-coding-system (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
```

Note that   `(setenv "LANG" ENCODING)` affects all subsequently created processes, which will inherit the `LANG`  value; `(set-buffer-process ...` and `(process-coding-system...` are buffer specific, so they require that the related (shell) buffer is current when called.

For the most cases this should work

```
M-S-: (setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8") 
M-x shell
M-S-: (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-unix 'utf-8-unix)
echo Straße > foo
```

On the contrary, using `(setenv "LANG" "en_US")` (without UTF-8), would print in the console or the file weird characters.

Chances there are that the proper values (UTF-8 based) are already the default ones.

As regards Windows,  the function `set-buffer-process-coding-system` still applies, but there is no  `LANG` variable in Windows. 
Windows represents the encodings in terms of *code page* numbers. Code pages  are often associated to several languages, for example most of the Western languages (though not US English) are encoded through code page 850. To learn about the system code page  consult the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP
```

When in the language setting you [change Windows default input language](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/102923-set-default-keyboard-input-language-windows-10-a.html), you might end up changing this value, e.g. switching from US to UK English changes  `OEMCP` value from 437 to 859. You can manually change  this value and there is a code page equivalent to UTF-8, that is  65001.
While 65001 (UTF-8) could be the standard in the future (like already is for Linux), given the relevant changes, you might break some non-unicode apps with CP 65001. Luckly, it is possible to easily set the code page in the Windows command prompt, rather than system wide, with the  `chcp` command (change code page). Under the Emacs perspective this boils down to:

```
M-x shell
chcp 65001
dir 
type foo.txt
```

In practice, assuming you have an English Windows, the command `dir` and `type` should be  able to  correctly show respectively filenames and file content in Russian or Chinese.