# Automatically change encoding of process buffers

Tags: shell, process, character-encoding, r

#### Platform

Windows 10 with GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32).

#### Goal

To set the encoding of process buffers to UTF-8.

I would like to set the input and output encoding of process buffers, like shell or the R Console (iESS), to UTF-8. By default, the iESS buffer is encoded as `iso-latin-1-dos` for output and `undecided-dos` for input.
If I ask Emacs:

```
M-S-: (process-coding-system (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))
```

I get:

```
(iso-latin-1-dos . undecided-dos)
```

As a result, special characters are mangled in the iESS output (although not in the input):

```
> print("Ä")
[1] "Ã\204"
>
```

#### What I've tried

I can change the encoding by invoking

```
M-S-: (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8 'utf-8)
```

as described in this [thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38381/shell-coding-system). The problem goes away, but I would like a permanent solution. So I tried to create hooks for several process buffers in my `.emacs`, like so:

```
; the hooks below should set the encoding of input to and output from a
; process buffer (like a shell, R console, or REPL) to UTF-8
; but somehow they don't.
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook (lambda () (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8 'utf-8)))
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda () (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8 'utf-8)))
(add-hook 'iESS-mode-hook
          (lambda () (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8 'utf-8)))
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook
          (lambda () (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8 'utf-8)))
```

Upon restarting Emacs, however, these settings have no effect. There is no error message, but the iESS and shell buffers still have the "wrong" encoding.

#### Questions

Ho can I fix the code above so it changes the encoding of the respective process buffer upon mode change? What would be a smarter way to achieve this? Is there a way to set all process buffers to utf-8 encoding without relying on individual hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `default-process-coding-system` to `'(utf-8 . utf-8)`. You can do this by adding this to your init file:

```lisp
(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8 . utf-8))
```

This and other useful variables are described in [chapter 33.10.5 Default Coding Systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Coding-Systems.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual. You may also be interested in the `process-coding-system-alist` variable.

You can open this and other manuals inside Emacs using `C-h i`.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot! Let me wait a day or two before accepting.